# What are the Intent to open Youtube app directly opened in Cardboard Viewer mode in android

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

Developers,

We have requirement to open 360 degree youtube videos from our applications.
But we want to open youtube app directly in **cardboard viewer mode playing videos**.

This is mainly for android application development. Thanks a lot in advance.

*Please note we already know how to open videos full screen and user presses cardboard button to go into mode.*

One such link of youtube video is [Visit Hamilton Island in 360˚ Virtual Reality with Qantas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJype_TafRk)

Comment: you can make it full screen using intent.putExtra("force_fullscreen",true); . I hope there also value for card view mode to make it forcefully view in card preview mode. please search for that may be it will help.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this yet??

Comment: Not yet, also project got on hold, so haven't put much effort on it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it looks like it is [not possible](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/FPZvA0fDZt0) right now.